# Create a lot of simple classes with one member

Tags: python, python-typing, mpi4py

Dealing with mypy `@overload` I wanted to have something like `enum` but for types.

You see, I deal with `mpi4py` and there is an argument `tag` that does nothing very useful, just separates messages (so that a receiver can know what data it is).

With different tags I send different data, types of data, but it is not even checked by the code editor, and I can get confused if I accidentally send data with a wrong tag.

My plan was to define a special function to send data

```
from typing import Tuple, Dict, Union, overload

from mpi4py import MPI


MPIComm = Union[MPI.Intracomm, MPI.Intercomm]

class TAG_NUMERIC:
    tag = 1
class TAG_STRING
    tag = 2
class TAG_DICT_STR_INT:
    tag = 3
class TAG_DICT_STR_TUPLE_INT_INT:
    tag = 4


@overload
def send(mpi_comm: MPIComm, dest: int, data: int, tag: TAG_NUMERIC) -> None: ...
@overload
def send(mpi_comm: MPIComm, dest: int, data: str, tag: TAG_STRING) -> None: ...
@overload
def send(mpi_comm: MPIComm, dest: int, data: Dict[str, int], tag: TAG_DICT_STR_INT) -> None: ...
@overload
def send(mpi_comm: MPIComm, dest: int, data: Dict[str, Tuple[int, int]], tag: TAG_DICT_STR_TUPLE_INT_INT) -> None: ...

def send(mpi_comm, dest, data, tag):
    mpi_comm.send(obj=data, dest=dest, tag=tag)
```

And call it this way:

```
some_int = 5
send(mpi_comm, 1, some_int, TAG_NUMERIC.tag)
some_string = 'abcd'
send(mpi_comm, 1, some_string, TAG_STRING.tag)
some_simple_dict = {"key1": 1, "key2": 2}
send(mpi_comm, 1, some_simple_dict, TAG_DICT_STR_INT.tag)
some_advanced_dict = {"key1": (1, 2), "key2": (3, 4)}
send(mpi_comm, 1, some_advanced_dict, TAG_DICT_STR_TUPLE_INT_INT.tag)
```

But it is so "not clever" to write so many lines to just define another type with a corresponding type in the class name.

Is there a possible way to define something like `enum` but for types (classes), those classes would contain only a single constant? Something like

```
class TAGS(int, typeEnum):
    HOUSE_NUMBER = 1      # corresponding data type: int
    STREET_NAME = 2       # corresponding data type: str
    NAMES_AND_AGES = 3    # corresponding data type: Dict[str, int]
    SOMETHING = 4         # corresponding data type: Dict[str, Tuple[int, int]]
```

And use it

```
var = TAGS.SOMETHING.value
print(var)  # output: 4
type(var)   # output: TAGS.SOMETHING
```

Comment: Why not just have separate methods for each type?  That would give a type checker more information to work with and might improve readability, at the cost of writing slightly more code.

Comment: @SamMason First, it will be illogical from the point of view of the functions' purpose - to reduce the amount of repeated code, and second, the functions will have rather strange names. However, your method is the same as my method of writing a lot of lines of code with class definitions, and it is not clear which of the two methods is better. Nevertheless, for me the amount of handwritten code comes first.

Comment: Why not add a wrapper func that tests the type of what you’re sending and figures out the tag?  `tag = {int : inttag}[type(data)]`?  Thats probably what overload is doing anyway.

Comment: Using the example in your question, what's wrong with `send_house_number(mpi_comm, 1, some_int)`?  Note that if you want to set up lots of methods like this, you can write a higher order function that would let you do something like `send_house_number = make_sender(int)`.

Comment: Are you just looking for generics? https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class dynamically with the `type()`. So, you can do like this.

```
from enum import IntEnum

class TAG(IntEnum):
    NUMERIC = 1
    STRING = 2

for k, v in TAG.__members__.items():
    cls_name = 'TAG_' + k
    globals()[cls_name] = type(cls_name, (), dict(tag=v.value))

print(TAG_NUMERIC, TAG_NUMERIC.tag)
# This will print "<class '__main__.TAG_NUMERIC'> 1".
```

Comment: Your method is interesting, but at runtime, Python does not perform type checks. And the biggest problem is that static checkers know nothing about this type, so they will indicate that this type does not exist. I need to have a statically resolvable method.

Comment: @MPEI_stud, you need to edit your question for that requirement on type checkers. Anyway, there's no built-in Python syntax for that. A possible workaround is to write a code generator which writes a conventional code that type checkers can understand.